# redirect all subdomains from http to https

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, subdomain

I redirect all http requests for my subdomain to https by using following code.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName subdomain.example.com
  Redirect 302 / https://subdomain.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Now my problem is how do I do it for all subdomains.

For example http:subdomain1.example.com should go to https:subdomain1.example.com and 
http:subdomain2.example.com should go to https:subdomain2.example.com

How do I do it for all subdomains without having to create one virtualhost for all of them

Answer (score 3):

What comes in mind would be to use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Something like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

However, note that Apache recommends the use of the `Redirect` directive in the Virtual Host configuration to achieve this.

From the doc *[When to not use mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/avoid.html)* :

> In the case of the http-to-https redirection, the use of RewriteRule
>   would be appropriate if you don't have access to the main server
>   configuration file, and are obliged to perform this task in a
>   .htaccess file instead.